# Django Celery RabbitMQ Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm new to celery, I followed the django / celery tutorial. I'm using rabbitmq. I have a simple function that uses celery:

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task
def test_celery(x, y):
    print x + y
    return None
```

When I run it with `delay` it doesn't work, it gives me a "connection reset by peer":

```
test_celery.delay("one ", "dos")
```

I'm running rabbitmq in another terminal, if I do

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_users
```

I get

```
alejoss []
guest   [administrator]
```

my `BROKER_URL` looks like this:

```
BROKER_URL = "amqp://alejoss:password@localhost://"
```

What am I missing. I'm new to Celery... please help.

Comment: What happens if it you try it with the default BROKER_URL? `amqp://guest@localhost//`

Comment: @PeterM.Elias It doesn't give me the error! No idea what was wrong. I guess I'll use the default url. It still doesn't print the strings to the terminal, but I guess that is a different error. Thnx!

Comment: 'it gives me a "connection reset by peer"' - can you please provide the full traceback or log message. what is your celery configuration? how are you running the celery worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your debugging feedback, I think you have an authentication issue with the user you setup for yourself. You may want to read-up more on access control here (https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html).

Sounds like it could be a permissions issue.

Here's the spoiler for you in case the documentation is too confusing at first :)

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p alejoss /  ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

The RabbitMQ gotcha here for newcomers is that newly created users by default have *NO* permissions.

Comment: I think it should be `-p / alejoss`, because `set_permissions [-p vhost] {user} {conf} {write} {read}`